# avahi-browse: can I only query the SRV records, without resolving hostname?

Tags: mdns, avahi

Suppose I publish a service with `--host` option using `avahi-publish -s`, e.g.:

```
avahi-publish -s --host=somewhere.example.com myservice _http._tcp 8080
```

Is there any way to tell `avahi-browse` to only return the domain name in SRV record, without resolving the host ?

The host domain name is a FQDN and has both `A` and `AAAA` records in the DNS server, but for some unknown reason, `avahi-browse` will only return `A` record for 99% of the time, even when the it's running on IPv6. That FQDN string will be used to compose `curl` command,  so there is really no need to resolve IP address in `avahi-browse`.